# Need help in implementing Single Sign On for Java / JEE application which runs on WAS7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, single-sign-on, solaris

We have a java / J2EE web application which runs on Websphere Application Server7 and this application is hosted on Solaris10.

We are trying to implement Single Sign On (i.e. When users logon to their domain computers / laptops and after that if they try to open the application, it needs to fetch the login credentials from the system login info and the same should be used for application login.) for this application.

Could you please suggest how we can proceed..? 
Any little amount help also will be very useful to us..

Thank you very much in advance..!!!

Comment: what have you tried so far? there are a number of SSO implementations which can be used to provide SSO, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations) each implementation is specific to a type of requirement, so you need to provide more details as to who/what will be your `AuthenticationProvider`, like LDAP, google, facebook etc.,

Comment: Are the clients also on Solaris or are the using a browser on a different machine?

Comment: @ThomasUhrig Clients are using browser from several platforms.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma Sry for the lack of information. We are planning to use Kerberos.

Comment: consider this material http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html

Comment: getting this error:
org.ietf.jgss.GSSException, major code: 11, minor code: 0 major string: General failure, unspecified at GSSAPI level minor string: Cannot get credential for principal service HTTP/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Does any one know what to do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users are in Windows Active directory and are logging in to the domain, then you can use built in SPNEGO/Kerberos authentication used in WAS, no need to use any external libraries.

Check chapter 7 in Implementing Kerberos in a WebSphere Application Server Environment redbook (www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247771.html) or in infocenter.

Answer (score -1):

So, you have Java server on Solaris and clients in various browsers on various platforms and you would prefer Kerberos?

Your main problem will be the clients, since browsers will behave different and operating systems will behave different. It will highly depend on which browser your clients use (and which version!) and if your clients are able to change settings of the browser (a lot of people are not able to do that). I cannot advice you for all platforms, but at least for Windows.

Take a look at https://github.com/dblock/waffle. This library should work on Windows with Chrome, FireFox and IE (since they all support Kerbers as far as I know). I used that library for a Java client, not in the browser, but you would simple configure servlet security filter to do the SSO, like this from their examples:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```